# Can not use a scalar as an array in making PHPExcel Reader

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpexcel

```
$file = 'upload/'.$filename;

    //read file from path
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objPHPExcel->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcel->load($file);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

    //$row = array();

    for($row=1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row){
        for($col=0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col){
        $row[$col] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col,$row)->getValue();
    }
    }
        echo "<pre>";print_r($row[$col]);echo "</pre>";
```

Here what is wrong with this `$row`. it tells me that the value type of `$row` is scalar. I am using array to put any cell from excel into my html.

I need to put this data into my mysql database. I'am using a Excel sheet, the sample sheet is :

(nama_lengkap, tempat_lahir, provinsi_lahir) ---> as header
(Anak pertama, Jakarta, DKI)
(Anak kedua, Bandung, Jawa Barat)
(Anak ketiga, Semarang, Jawa Tengah)

**Imagine table data:**

```
| id | nama        | tempat_lahir | provinsi_lahir |

|----|-------------|--------|-------|

| 1  | John | Semarang  | Jawa tengah    |

| 2  | Meresa | Bandung | Jawa Barat    |

| 3  | Mike  | Jakarta   | Dki    |
```

Comment: do like this echo `"<pre>";print_r($row[]);echo "</pre>";` since `$col` is defined only within loop

Comment: I see, im trying using an array to put this $row into my table inside mysql

Answer (score 0):

Another everything is fine. But you are overwriting value in `$row` again and again within `for` loop. Here is the code should look like:

```
$file = 'upload/' . $filename;
//read file from path
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcel->load($file);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

$excelData = array();

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
        $excelData[$row][$col] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($excelData);
echo "</pre>";
```

Take an array `$excelData` and store data from excel sheet in it.

Comment: this is great. but now, im confused how to put this array ($ExcelData) with table header ('nama','tempat-lahir','provinsi_lahir') :'(

Comment: Post some sample excel sheet data and how you want to show that. So that I can understand.

Comment: I have made a sheet table in my post (edited). I hope you know what I write

Comment: If I directly put the array, it will be error. it says Array to string conversion